# The cloud service you have chosen is deployed in a region or affinity group that does not currently support virtual machines

Tags: azure, virtual-machine, powershell-ise

## Problem:

I am attempting to add a new VM as a second domain contoller to an existing domain and error when attempting to add it to the same Cloud Service.

## Steps1:

Created a virtual network

Assigned an Affinity Group to the network (cloudAG)

Scripted the creation of a VM following the protocol to add a DC with DNS.

As part of this process a Cloud Service was created for this VM (DCcloudservice) in the Affinity Group.

Scripted the creation of a second VM , when attempting to related it to the same Cloud Service using this line:

$service = 'DCcloudservice'

(please note i have amended all other parameters and am 100% sure this command value is causing the conflict error)

## Error1:

The following error is displayed:

> New-AzureVM : "An exception occurred when calling the ServiceManagement API. HTTP Status Code: 409. Service Management Error Code: ConflictError. Message: The specified DNS name is already taken.. 
>   Operation Tracking ID: 121129c1212be49c8be9f81411178a61ac."
>   At line:25 char:1
>   + New-AzureVM -ServiceName $service -AffinityGroup $AG -VMs $MyVM1 -DnsSettings $m ...
>   + ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
>       + CategoryInfo          : CloseError: (:) [New-AzureVM], ServiceManagementClientException
>       + FullyQualifiedErrorId : Microsoft.WindowsAzure.Management.ServiceManagement.IaaS.PersistentVMs.NewAzureVMCommand

## Steps2:

So using the Azure Mgt Portal I try to create the same VM. When selecting the existing DC Cloud Service name I receive the message:

## Error2:

"The cloud service you have chosen is deployed in a region or affinity group that does not currently support virtual machines"

Following STEP 7 in this article:

"Step 7 - Add Second Domain Controller"

> http://community.adxstudio.com/blogs/shan/2013-07-02-setting-up-an-active-directory-network-in-windows/

It suggests:

"What this does is creates the virtual machine in an existing cloud service so that it can be added to an availability group later".

## Question:

Simply put, POWERSHELL ISE and AZURE MGT PORTAL do not allow me to add a new VM to an existing Cloud Service and I cannot understand why.

Thank you for any help.

EDITED TO ADD the region is NORTH EUROPE.

---

## 29/07/13 EDITED TO ADD RESPONSE TO TABREZ:

Thank you for the reply. Hope the detail below helps explain.

1) the VNET was created within the last month in NORTH EUROPE. Access to this specific sub was 25/06/13.

2) this is the script used for domain joining a new vm. Works to add a node to the domain perfectly if i create a new cloud serice value. If I use the existing DC cloud service value i get the DNS error explained above.

> $myDNS = New-AzureDNS -Name 'myDNS' -IPAddress '172.16.0.4'
>
> $image = 'Windows-Server-2012-Datacenter-201305.01-en.us-127GB.vhd'
>
> $service = 'cloudDC1'
>
> $AG = 'cloudAG'
>
> $vnet = 'cloudvnet'
>
> $pwd = 'password'
>
> $size = 'Small'
>
> $vmname = 'DC2'
>   $MyVM1 = New-AzureVMConfig -name $vmname -InstanceSize $size -ImageName $image |
>       Add-AzureProvisioningConfig -WindowsDomain -Password $pwd -Domain 'domain' ->DomainPassword 'password' -DomainUserName 'adminuser' -JoinDomain 'domain.COM'|
>       Set-AzureSubnet -SubnetNames 'Back'
>
> New-AzureVM -ServiceName $service -AffinityGroup $AG -VMs $MyVM1 -DnsSettings $myDNS -VNetName $vnet

3) Another Q. There are many articles about adding the FIRST DC to a VNET using powershell and why its important to make the value $MYDNS = 127.0.0.1. When using DOMAIN JOIN to add an ADDITIONAL DC to the same domain I must enter the first DC IP address as the $MYDNS value for the domain join to be successful.

If using 127.0.0.1 it cannot find the domain.

If i use 172.16.0.4 as the $myDNS value for the additional DC and DC1 then fails the additional DC (DC2) surly has a problem resoling DNS queries ?

No info on the net explaining how to add a second domain controller / additional domain controller / backup domain controller / replica domain controller on AZURE that addresses the $myDNS issues that is so important to creating the first DC DNS correctly using 127.0.0.1 loopback IP.

Please note my VNET has the following DNS server IPS

172.16.0.4 (dc1).
172.16.0.5 (dc2) once created.
8.8.8.8 google1
8.8.8.4 google2
192.168.1.3 (site to site VPN DC2)
192.168.1.1 (site to site VPN DC1)

Site to site VPN currently down as KEY keeps changing if you dont use CISCO or JUNIPER routers. I need to install an ISA server to maintain this connection.

---

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Took a bit of time and testing but got answer from Azure support.

My original request included Affinity Group Value:

```
New-AzureVM -ServiceName $service -AffinityGroup $AG -VMs $MyDC -DnsSettings $myDNS -VNetName $vnet
```

Removing the Affinity Group allowed the process to proceed:

```
New-AzureVM -ServiceName $service -VMs $MyDC -DnsSettings $myDNS -VNetName $vnet
```

Hope that helps someone.

Cheers
Scott

AffinityGroup parameter must be used in the provisioning command only when we are creating a new IAAS VM and in turn create a new implicit cloud service.

Answer (score 1):

It looks like for PS that you're attempting to create a new cloud service for the second VM that has the same DNS name as the one you've already created. Can you share your exact call to New-AzureVM with us so we can take a look?

For the issues you're having deploying the VM through the management portal, if you've confirmed that you've selected the same cloud service in which you deployed the first VM, you'll need to open a support ticket so we an take a closer look at your subscription. The error message you're seeing typically shows up when a user creates an affinity group before the region supported virtual machines. If you've just started following this tutorial and created an affinity group in the past few days, or even weeks, that would not be the culprit.

Comment: Thanks for reply, please see additional detail above.

Comment: For the issue you're having deploying a VM using the management portal, can you share your subscription ID with us? E-mail me at tabrezm[at]microsoft[dot]com. Also share any details about what cloud service you were attempting to use when you saw the error.

Comment: For the PS deployment issue, the New-AzureVM cmdlet will attempt to create a new cloud service using the ServiceName parameter. Check out this blog post for how to add multiple VMs to the same cloud service: http://michaelwasham.com/2012/07/13/connecting-windows-azure-virtual-machines-with-powershell/.

Comment: The michaelwasham link you have supplied suggests either a VM can be added to a CLOUDSERVICE or a VM can be added to a VNET not both. I was attempting to do both. VNET to allow domain join and AD benefits + cloudservice to allow for the potential to load balance.

Comment: opened a support ticket with MS , will post result once it works.

Comment: Feedback to date from MS support to date after they recreated this issue "Looks like the documentation is incorrect or some of the commands are incorrect."